# LM35 temp sesnor equation for arduino uno which connected to matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, arduino, equation, adc, analog-digital-converter

Hi I'm new in matlab GUI

I am trying to create an axes plot the temperature which comes from LM35 through arduino uno to matlab

I used the following code to read the analog voltage, `readVoltage(a,0)`
I get a values about 0.28 - 0.30 but I don't know exactly what this values exactly means is it the the real `temperature/100` or what? I know there is an ADC inside arduino converts the input voltage to another range (0-1023) when I use `analogRead()` on the arduino side. Does it also work here or not? I confused about this thing when I should assume it is 0-1023 or directly get the reading.

Answer (score 2):

The arduino ADC reads a voltage and outputs a number according to

1. the reference voltage
2. the bit width of the ADC

in this case I suppose that you are using the 5V reference and 10 bit mode, so

```
Vmeasured = NumberFromADC * 5V / 1024
```

Now, according to the LM35 datasheet the output voltage is

```
Vout = 10mV/°C * T
```

inverting the equation:

```
T = Vout / (10mV/°C) = NumberFromADC * 5V / 1024 / (10mV/°C) = NumberFromADC * 500 / 1024
```

(of course expressed in °C)

BTW I suggest you to change the voltage reference to an internal one, since the 5V are not stable and precise enough to have a good measuring system. More info [here](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogReference).

And, of course, if you change the reference voltage you will need to change the equation since the reference itself will not be 5V anymore.

Comment: thank you
but my question was about ADC and readVoltage() command which on matlab side I think it is gives me the input voltage directly or what ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. When I read Matlab I thought you were using just for displaying rather than programming the Arduino. My bad. Anyway... In matlab you just have `readVoltage`, which gives you the converted voltage. In arduino IDE, on the other side, you have `analogRead`, which gives you the ADC reading (i.e. 0-1023). [Here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/ref/readvoltage.html) you can find some documentation about the `readVoltage` function.